# How to search for a particular word in a sentence

Tags: java, netbeans

I am actually a newbie to Java and was trying to do a small project. So, in my project, I want to allow the user to enter a sentence, and I want the program to search for particular words in the sentence and give outputs based on that. I use NetBeans to develop my applications.

My code is something like this

```
String Sentence=jTextField1.getText();
if (Sentence.equals("Hello")
{
jTextField2.setText("Hello was found");
}
else if (Sentence.equals("Donkey")
{
jTextField2.setText("Donkey was found");
}
```

I know that this code makes no sense and wont run, but I put it so that people can get a general idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Please help me.

Comment: I think you're looking for `contains()`.

Comment: Please have a look at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)). There's a method called `contains`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply azurefrog and QBrute. I saw this previously as well, but I am not sure as to how to combine this with an if else operator. Is there any way to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.contains` like so:

```
String Sentence = jTextField1.getText();
if (Sentence.contains("Hello")) {
    jTextField2.setText("Hello was found");
} else if (Sentence.contains("Donkey")) {
    jTextField2.setText("Donkey was found");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was stuck on this for so long and you have no idea as to how much this helped !!

Comment: @ParameshSriram Anytime ;)